# ember http-mock request.body is undefined

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

just migrated to ember-cli 0.1.12 and now http-mock is not working for me.

Its working fine for get request . request.query returns all the query parameters.

However for POST request i cannot get the request paramters as request.body is undefined.

Can some one let me know how to access the request body in ember http-mock?

Answer (score 1):

As I've also said in the issue tracker, this is due to a change in Ember CLI where the body-parser was removed by default because it would affect other middlewares.

I've opened a PR with some instructions for your case. https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/pull/3211

Comment: I am currently having this issue, months after it's been fixed. I'm either doing something wrong or I'm just cursed.

Comment: @MilkyWayJoe have you follow the instructions in the PR I linked?

Comment: Yeah, I've installed the body parser, but I was confused first 'coz the thread in github had different ways to set it up. I think I got it now. Forgot to follow up.

Comment: I've followed the instructions in the PR mentioned but req.body is still undefined for a POST. I can log the entire request to the console which has all the headers etc. but the body does not seem to be there. However, the browser console shows the request payload body in the network request. For a GET req.params works ok.

For those who got this to work did you have to do anything else besides what is mentioned in the referenced pull request? Any ideas what I could be doing wrong?

Comment: @Ian I've added an answer with example, does this help?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with req.body being undefined. Here are the steps I followed:

1) Install body-parser

```
npm install body-parser
```

2) You need to specify for each mock file that it requires the body-parser. So for example my /server/mocks/addresses.js is now:

```
module.exports = function(app) {
  var express = require('express');
  var addressesRouter = express.Router();

  ...

  addressesRouter.post('/', function (req, res) {
    var address = req.body;
    address.id = addresses.length + 1;
    addresses.push(address);
    res.status(201).send({
      'address': address
    });
  });

  ...

    app.use('/api/addresses', require('body-parser').json(), addressesRouter);
```

So basically you need to add a second (middle) argument of `require('body-parser').json()` to the final `app.use`.

req.body should now work and no longer be undefined.